# Fatal error while using kartik\mpdf\Pdf in yii 2.0

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I am getting following error online

Fatal error: Class 'kartik\mpdf\Pdf' not found in /home/junaidali3/public_html/magicsalon/config/web.php on line 12

where web.php is like following:

http://grab.by/GYjE

everything is working fine on wamp but when i try to run it online server it is giving fatal error

Comment: Did you properly run composer on online server ?

Comment: issue has been solved there was some missing vendor files which were not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You must add this line to autoload_psr4.php :

```
'mPDF\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mpdf')
```

If mpdf extension is in root of vendor folder